# Long Text change to rich text still only allows 255 characters in ACCESS 2016 db

Tags: ms-access, text, format

After almost a week of trying the solutions here and on other sites, I'm hoping someone can give me an answer before I move on to MySQL.

I need more than 255 characters in a field in my ACCESS db, so I selected the Long Text Data Type in design view. Per other instructions, I also changed the text format in Field Properties from Plain to rich text. Unfortunately, I'm still limited to 255 chars. I'm using ACCESS 2016. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Maybe this is your problem (`memo`is `long text` in `Ms Access 2016`) http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Unfortunately, none of the recommendations applied to my issue or solved solved it, so I'll go with MySQL. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Access 2016 most definitely allows long rich text:

[image]

[image]